# Not able to install the extensions in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google, facebook, google-hangouts

Could not install package:

```
'UTILITY_PROCESS_CRASHED_WHILE_TRYING_TO_INSTALL'. Could not install package because a utility process crashed. Try restarting Chrome and trying again.
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I simply had to restart Chrome.

You could use this command:

```
pkill chrome
```

Chrome was running in the background and not properly restarting.  Once I killed the process, I had no problems.

Comment: I noticed a couple of things: the little dot under the Chrome icon disappears "at some point" (probably when it gets upgraded). After that Chrome fails in all sorts of ways. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1855489 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1616650

Answer (score 3):

I have just found this [guide](http://graysonpeddie.com/utility-process-crashed-while-trying-to-install-in-google-chrome/) for that error, that actually it is a simple way to fix the problem, maybe it will be ok for you.

From the command line:

Go in the home folder and open the `.config` folder (in this folder are placed the application you have installed such as skype, chrome...)

```
cd ~/.config
```

Do a simple backup of the google-chrome directory by renaming it:

```
mv google-chrome google-chrome-back
```

And try to run again chrome. It will create a nwe google-chrome directory.

If it does not works try to unistall and install again chrome.

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Hi CabalT, link only answer will likely be deleted, please include the external content into your answer, keeping the link as reference.

Comment: +1 Wow! This is great - well done for this edit! I hope you stick around this site :D However, I'm not convinced a reinstall is needed...

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this to work by fluke. Some sights said that the problem with adding extensions to chrome browser was found on the later versions of chrome. Hence they suggested that we downgrade to chrome 34. I did that.. After that I could add the postman extension without an error, but after adding the postman app wouldn't launch at all. It wouldn't even throw an error. Just failed silently. Finally I gave up and upgraded chrome to the latest version. To my surprise I found that the postman extension that I had previously installed was now available on my list of chrome apps and I could easily launch and use it without a problem :)... So finally it was a combination = Install postman app with chrome 34 + Upgraded to chrome later version ie 46.0.2490 to launch & use app

Comment: There is a lot of text, but not really any clear instructions on what fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just handled this problem.

**Step 1.**

Uninstall current version of chrome(Mine was chrome version 46) as described by @CabaIT using purge.

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome
```

**Step 2.**

Install an older stable version of chrome (In my case, used google-chrome-stable- version 34.0.1847).

**Step 3**

Install all needed chrome extensions without package installation error as there is no installation error in the older version of chrome.

**Step 4**

Then updgrade chrome to current stable version using,

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable
```

Now you will have extensions installed + an updated chrome version. Problem solved.